# WCF JSONP jQuery is not passing correct status

Tags: jquery, wcf, jsonp, http-status-codes

My issue is very straight forward. I want the correct status code passed through to my success or error methods through a JSONP result when its calling a WCF service.

When WCF is handling a jsonp response, and the status code is not 200, it sends the status code as the 2nd parameter in the callback method. This seems logical to me, but I cannot find JSONP specs anywhere to see if its correct to specs.

The returned content is:  jQuery123456(null, 401);
jQuery then treats this as a success, calls my success method, but the 401 is no where to be found. I made sure of this by doing a console.dir(arguments);

What I'm going to be doing now, is overriding the callback method name and handle all that myself, but I'd rather not have to do that.

Something like this needs to be supported in jQuery.

**Update:** You cannot override the method because then jQuery thinks there was an error and pops up an error message.

Comment: I've been looking into using a custom ajax filter? Maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is because JQuery can't know the status of the request because it is done via a script tag, not an XHR object. '200' is passed into the done() callback if you look into the depths of JQuery.

Comment: I understand that. WCF, however, will return the status code as a second argument in the JSONP response. I am attempting to make jQuery support this behavior in it's JSONP calls.

Answer (score 0):

Do you know you can't access to the status code with the JSONP method, you can read this answer from an Angularjs developer it's pretty clear :
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1423#issuecomment-10768224

Thomas

Comment: That's the whole point of this post. In order to get the status code you follow the standard of passing it back as the second parameter in the JSONP javascript call. jQuery is not properly sending all methods returned into the method back to your calling method. It only pulls out the first argument.